# How do I add Entry Types to URL?

Tags: entries, entry-type, url

In the Sections settings ("Entry URL Format") I would like to add an entry property tag for Entry Type.

```
discography/{slug}
```

Answer (score 11):

Sure just do this

```
discography/{type}/{slug}
```

Comment: Format your code.

Comment: sure there you go..

Comment: Another thing: if you replied me on my comment and I am not an owner of this post, I don't get notified: to notify add @nicael (or other name).

Comment: Fair enough @nicael.  Also worth noting to you a better way to suggest edits is to make them yourself and the answerer can approve your edits

Comment: I couldn't just edit. Not enough characters.

Comment: I mean just formatting is not enough to be able to suggest edit.